# Not able to access Google REST Api using Service Account

Tags: google-bigquery, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-oauth-java-client

I need to access [Google's BigQuery REST Api Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/) with Service Account using Http client library.
So, I tried the code provided in the article [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

It gives me the compilation error in the below line.

Algorithm.RSA256(null, privateKey)

Code below:

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream("service_account.json"));

    PrivateKey privateKey = credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKey();
    String privateKeyId = credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId();

    try {

        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, privateKey);

        String signedJwt = JWT.create().withKeyId(privateKeyId)
                .withIssuer("123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .withSubject("123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .withAudience("https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore")
                .withIssuedAt(new Date(now)).withExpiresAt(new Date(now + 3600 * 1000L)).sign(algorithm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note:
Algorithm.RSA256() accept java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey 
whereas Google Api returns java.security.PrivateKey

Could anyone help me in this?

Comment: This might help https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#service_accounts

Answer (score 0):

What I found out looking into the Implementation: The RSAPrivateKey inherits from PrivateKey, so if you cast it (maybe type-check first), then you should be good to go!